# Strings in Matlab

Tags: regex, string, matlab, twitter, cell

I have a file of tweets that I have read into MATLAB using `dataread` and they're stored in a cell.  I wanted to find the average number of characters in the tweets. How would I go about doing that? Here is the code I have so far:

```
fid=fopen('tweets.txt');                               
lines = dataread('file', 'tweets.txt', '%s', 'delimiter', '\n');
```

I was thinking I could use something along the lines of `cellfun` but I'm unsure how to format it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try `cellfun(@numel,lines)`, it returns the length of each line.

btw: `fid=fopen('tweets.txt');` is unnecessary if you use `dataread` this way. Simply delete the line.

Comment: The function-name version `cellfun('prodofsize',lines)` will presumably be faster.